# Relation between squared standard normals and $\chi^2$

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test

I have a very basic question regarding introductory statistics. It is a well known result that if we have two standardized normally distributed variables $X$ and $Y$, then $$
X^{2}+Y^{2}\sim\chi^{2}(2)
$$

What does this really mean? In practical terms, would $X$ and $Y$ be random normal vectors? Would then the squared sum of the vectors be as above? Or does this type of notation indicate a realized *value* of the random process? Are we looking at two specific realizations of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ have to be *independent* standard normal for the relation to hold.

Comment: You might be confused over random variables, random vectors, realizations of random variables etc. You could find [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable) post describing random variables helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose

- $X$ is standard normal random variable; denote $U:=X^2$
- $Y$ is standard normal random variable; denote $V:=Y^2$
- $X$ and $Y$ are independent

then

- $Z:=U+V$ is a $\chi^2(2)$ random variable.

Here $U:=X^2$ is a random variable generated in the following way: whatever realization is generated by $X$, we take the square of this realization and call it a realization of $U$. The same with $V$ and $Y$. (Any realization of $X$ is univariate, and its square (a realization of $U$) is univariate, too. The same with $Y$ (and $V$).)

Comment: Thank you for your clear response (+1). I wonder if you could possibly provide with a scenario where this operation would come handy.

Comment: Here is a scenario.  Suppose we do two different statistical tests and want to combine them.  We know the first test gives a statistic $Z_1$ that is standard normal under the null hypothesis (H0: $\mu = 0$ and Ha: $\mu\not= 0$).  Similarly, the second test also has a statistic $Z_2$ that is standard normal under the null hypothesis.  The first test was performed independently of the second test.  To combine these tests, we can form a new statistic $X^2 = Z_1^2 + Z_2^2$.  Since the sum of the square of two independent standard normal random variable has the chi-square distribution with 2 df...

Comment: ... we can perform the combined test by looking for a rejection region for $X^2$ using chi-squared tables with 2 df, because this will be its distribution under the null hypothesis H0: $\mu_1=0 \ and\ \mu_2=0$.

Comment: @AlaskaRon very nice. Ty!

Comment: I have a follow up question: if indepedent squared realizations of X and Y when summed are distributed as exactly chi-squared with 2 df, then why is it the case that when I generate 2 random vectors of X and Y and square them and sum then, the mean that I get of the new variable is not exactly 2? Does it have something to do with LLN?

Comment: You cannot sum them completely, like `sum(x^2+y^2)` in R where `x` and `y` are standard normal vectors. Also, `mean(x^2+y^2)` is not supposed to be $\chi^2(2)$-distributed. But if you have a vector `x^2+y^2`, then each of its elements should be distributed as $\chi^2(2)$.